# JS Regex to add text in between text (raw html)?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to prevent tabnabbing for raw text that gets set as HTML. For example, if I have `Check out more information here: <a href="linktobadsite.com">Click me</a>`, I want to be able to add a `'rel="noreferrer"` to only the properties inside the anchor tag. The best way I have come up with is `value.replace(/href/g, 'rel="noreferrer" href');` but if I had such text like "Set the href inside the anchor tag" it would display as "Set the href 'rel="noreferrer" inside the anchor tag". What's the proper expression to add the noreferrer only in between `<a href="" _target>` text?

Comment: Saying "there can be any text that mimics a valid anchor" is basically saying "it's impossible".

Comment: If you are doing this in JS then make use of the DOM and XPath. Regex is thoroughly the wrong tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are receiving this text from the users and would like
to display it to other users, minimizing the opportunities for an attacker
to be successful at stealing some information.

So let's say that you parse this text and have a HTML representation in JS, then you could walk this object and for every anchor add the `rel=noreferrer` property.

Then you can serialize this to a string again and show it "safely" to other users.

Never trust the user input, always validate it.

This is a lot of work.

My take on this problem would be to send an additional
header with your response. The `Referrer-Policy` header
would work best for your case as you can set it to `same-origin` and be done with this.

Once your user load your website (and you send all the headers and the content) the browser will
remember this policy

> same-origin
>   A referrer will be sent for same-site origins, but cross-origin requests will send no referrer information.

This means that for every link pointing to a different domain the brower will not send any referrer information when the link is followed.

You can find more information about the values of the
`Referrer-Policy` header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy).

Obviously this will enforce the policy site-wide, or at
least until the browser receives a new header value.

If you are unable to set an additional header you can
set this policy using a `meta` tag in the HTML document

```
<meta name="referrer" content="same-origin">
```